# How can I fix this error with my discordJS token

Tags: discord.js

What am I doing wrong?
Error: **const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('The bot is online.');
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing a string ('TOKEN') as your token, rather than the actual token?

Comment: I am using my token, just made it ('TOKEN') for privacy reasons on here
@thesuaf

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using, and what exactly is not working? (what error is appearing?)

Comment: @theusaf discord.js 13.1.0 and im getting this error:

/home/runner/The-House-Cup/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:32
    const token = this.client.token ?? this.client.accessToken;
                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Comment: Make sure you upgrade your nodejs version to 16.6 or above. See https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start for more information to upgrade from v12 to v13

Answer (score 0):

Your version of **Node.js** is out of date and the version you are using of **discord.js** requires a recent version of **node**. Try downloading a **recent version** of **node.js** and updating your **discord.js**, after that just start your bot normally.

Download here: https://nodejs.org/en/